# Seeing numerous Logging Gap errors related to OOTB Image Slider after AppPool Recycle

Tags: 2013, application-pool

In SP2013, I am getting thousands of `forced logging gap` errors that appear to relate to **get requests** for images (the thumbnails) in an image slider after an **app pool recycle**. The errors are along the lines of

> Forced logging gap.. object not found in live item cache.

Is there a bug with the out of box image slider?